# Upgrading react-select version from 1.0.0 to 3.1.0

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to upgrade react-select version from 1.0.0-rc.10 to 3.1.0. I'm getting following error

> jquery.js?eedf:3869 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

My current react version is - 15.6.2

I want to upgrade react-select for the following reason:
 When user type in react-select( Component) there is a little delay i see in box(where i've used  Component). The text in the box appears in little late (300ms ~ 500ms)

Current code (v1.0.0) for Select:

```
const props = {
 className: 'search-combobox',
 placeholder,
 onChange: this._onSelectionChange.bind(this),
 onSelect: this.props.onSelectedItem,
 options: this.state.immSearchOptions.toJS(),
 filterOptions: this._filterOptions.bind(this),
 onInputChange: this._onInputChange.bind(this),
 valueKey: 'id',
};

<Select {...props}
  autoFocus={true}
  clearable={true}
  closeOnSelect={true}
  maxMenuHeight={300}
  escapeClearsValue={true}
  onBlurResetsInput={false} />
```

Comment: can you add some code please? thanks

Comment: i don't know what code to add. Its like, i'm getting error on very first line import Select from "react-select";

Comment: what about the code where it delays?

Comment: updated the question with code i'm using for Select component